# Catching const char* exception in c++

Tags: c++, try-catch

I make an exception for my program:

```
class PortNotDefined: public exception
{
public:

const char* what() const throw()
{
    return "Puerto no definido o no disponible";
}
} PortNotDefined;
```

And later, I use a try-catch block like this:

```
try{.....}
catch(const char* a){
    std::string error(a);
    ...
}
```

But it not catch the exception, I dont know if I defined well the exception or is problem in the try-catch

Thanks for your time^^

Comment: Did you *throw* a `PortNnotdefined` exception? If so, any special reason you're not *catching* a `const PortNotDefined&` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, you exception is of type PortNotDefined so you should be catching with `catch(const PortNotDefined& d)` and not catch(const char* a). returning const char* does not make it a const char* exception.

Secondly, in your try block something needs to throw PortNotDefined. Otherwise, the exception will never be caught because it was never thrown.

Thirdly, I think you have a syntax error when declaring you exception class. Here is a complete example that works:

```
class PortNotDefined: public exception
{
public:

    const char* what() const throw()
    {
        return "Puerto no definido o no disponible";
    }
};

void methodThatWillThrowPortNotDefined ()   
{
    throw PortNotDefined();
}

void test()
{
    try{
        methodThatWillThrowPortNotDefined();
    }
    catch(const PortNotDefined& pnd){
        std::string error(pnd.what());
        cerr << "Exception:" << error << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd avoid exception specifications too... http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill22.htm

Comment: Please change catch(PortNotDefined& pnd) to catch(const PortNotDefined& pnd)

Answer (score 2):

Or general, you could catch const ref to std::exception, beacause of inheritance hierarchy.

```
catch(const std::exception& ex)
```

Answer (score 1):

`catch(const char* a)` will catch an object of type `const char*`. If you throw an object of type `PortNotDefined` you need a catch clause that will catch that type, typically `catch(PortNotDefined d)` or `catch(const PortNotDefined& d)`.

Comment: I put catch(PortNotDefined name) but it tells me an error "sintax error, identifier "portnotdefined"

PortNotDefined is in a PortNotDefined.h

Comment: Show the code that failed. From the message, it looks like the code tried to use `portnotdefined` when the actual name is `PortNotDefined`, but that's speculation.

Comment: error: C2061: error de sintaxis : identificador 'PortNotDefined'

In English: sintax error: identifier 'PortNotDefined'.
And fail in: catch(PortNotDefined name)
    {

Comment: try{

            inm.moveVectorArticulation(RIGHT_PART,vArtic,posiciones);

    }
    catch(PortNotDefined a)
    {       std::string jo(a.what());
            error->putPort(jo.c_str());
            error->exec();

    }

Comment: That code does not have a definition of `PortNotDefined`, so it can't possibly compile. I'm skeptical that that's actually all of the code, though. As always, put together the smallest example you can that shows the problem.